# Django: Annotate model with a prefix sum

Tags: python, django, annotate

I have a model `TimeTrial` that aggregates an ordered list of `Leg`s.

```
class TimeTrial(models.Model):
    objects = TimeTrialManager()

class Leg(models.Model):
    timetrial = models.ForeignKey(TimeTrial)
    duration = models.FloatField()
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def duration_prefix_sum(self):
        qs = Leg.objects.filter(timetrial=self.timetrial,
                                order__lte=self.order)
        return qs.aggregate(Sum('duration'))

class TimeTrialManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(TimeTrialManager, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(leg_count=Count('leg'))
        qs = qs.annotate(duration=Sum('leg__duration'))
        return qs
```

(Stripped-down version of [the actual models](https://github.com/TK-IT/kasse/blob/185b84308f47611c6272574b550dff9f5a1e2930/kasse/models.py#L111-L159).)

The `TimeTrialManager` annotates each `TimeTrial` with the number of `Leg`s and the sum of `Leg.duration`. I would like to compute the `duration_prefix_sum` using Django's `annotate`/`aggregate` in a similar way, so I don't incur a database hit when I display every leg's `duration_prefix_sum` in `timetrial.leg_set.all()`.

I know I can write Python code to compute it:

```
timetrial.leg_set_annotated = []
s = 0
for l in timetrial.leg_set.all():
    s += l.duration
    l.duration_prefix_sum_computed = s
    timetrial.leg_set_annotated.append(l)
```

But I would rather use annotate/aggregate/Case/When of Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, but I'm not sure it's entirely robust. I've [implemented it in my project](https://github.com/TK-IT/kasse/blob/b95e93f249ce31be68599fb0c1ee7918953b59f8/kasse/managers.py#L35-L36).

We add the filter `timetrial__leg__order__lte=F('order')` to add a join containing all Legs with order less or equal to the current.
Then, we add the annotation `duration_prefix_sum` as `Sum('timetrial__leg__duration')`, which computes the prefix sum.

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
qs = Leg.objects.filter(timetrial__leg__order__lte=F('order'))
qs = qs.annotate(duration_prefix_sum=Sum('timetrial__leg__duration'))
```

I think this will fail if the code that uses this queryset makes another annotation/filter on `'timetrial__leg'`, so additions to make this more robust are welcome.